# JS file not linking to html

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom

for the life of me, I can't figure out why my JS file is not loading into my HTML while I'm trying to do hands-on practise to learn React JS.

My html code is as follows:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
        <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
        <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
        </head>
    <body>
        <div Id="test"></div>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

My JS code is as follows:

```
ReactDOM.render(<p> Hi there</p>, document.getElementById("test"))
```

The result I get is always a blank document.

Edit (15/10)

I tried adding the script type with text/babel and reverting the version to 17 and left the script.js file as is.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
        <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
        <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
        </head>
    <body>
        <div id="test"></div>
        <script src="script.js" type="text/babel"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

THe result I had gotten is this ( Can't seem to upload images)

```
Under Console:
-You are using the in-browser Babel transformer. Be sure to precompile your scripts for production

-Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///D:/Ventures/React%20tutorial/script.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, isolated-app, brave, https, chrome-untrusted, data, chrome-extension, chrome.

-GET file:///D:/Ventures/React%20tutorial/script.js net::ERR_FAILED
s @ babel.min.js:24
(anonymous) @ babel.min.js:24
o @ babel.min.js:24
u @ babel.min.js:24
f @ babel.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ babel.min.js:1

Under Network:
I get a CORS ERROR and the type no longer is a script but a xhr
```

I also tried changing the version back to 18 and update the code in my JS file that was provided in the answers but I got the same issue

I tried finding a precompiler but apparently VS Code has an in-built one for JS so I'm not too sure how to resolve this.

Comment: Do you see errors in the browser console?

Comment: Possible typo: `id` not `Id`.

Comment: Hi thank you all for the responses. 

@LajosArpad , From the browser console under network i dont see any issues. Please see newly uploaded image :)

Andy, i tried both and neither works

Comment: `ReactDOM.render(<p> Hi there</p>, document.getElementById("test"))` <-- That is JSX, not JS. You can't run JSX directly in the browser: you need to run a build step to convert it to browser-executable JS.

Comment: Hey @Dai, thanks :) I tried adding the type, but unfortunately to no avail :/

Comment: By the looks of it, it seems you are opening the html file directly in the browser, which will not work. You need a server. In the tutorial they use their own IDE (something Scrimba probably made themselves which serves the files via a server, just guessing). Using VSCode as your IDE, you can install an extension that can serve your files via server. I for example use one called `Live Server` by Ritwick Dey, but you can use whatever is comfortable for you. With `Live Server` its as easy as right clicking `index.html` and choose `Open with Live Server`.

Comment: @Bqardi Thank you so much! yes i went ahead directly with the scrimba platform to learn the syntax and in the later section they covered how to set it up in an IDE and how to display it properly. It still lacks some functionality but at least it' indirectly solves the problem. :) if you post this as an answer, i could upvote this :)

Answer (score 1):

You're neglecting type="text/babel".

```
<script src="script.js" type="text/babel"></script>
```

Also, if you use `ReactDOM.render`, you'll see error messages in your console, because that's for React version 17.

Answer (score 0):

I think importing js as script doesn't work for react. You should go step by step from ReactJs document from link below to know how to link react to html:

https://reactjs.org/

and also change `Id="test"` to `id="test"`

Comment: Hey Behrad, I was following a tutorial where they did the exact same thing and it worked. And even if i use it as just a JS file it doesn't work either URL here: youtube.com/watch?v=bMknfKXIFA8 14:50

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to elaborate on Julianna's answer.

React made some major changes from v17 to v18, especially for the render method.
So to get rid of the warnings, you should either use CDN's for version 17 or update the code to use the new syntax for rendering.

By updating this:

```js
ReactDOM.render(<p> Hi there</p>, document.getElementById("test"))
```

to this:

```js
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("test")).render(<h1>Hi there</h1>);
```

And the part in the tutorial that you missed where the speaker explains that you should include `type="text/babel"` is here:

[React Course - Beginner's Tutorial for React JavaScript Library [2022] - 11:12](https://youtu.be/bMknfKXIFA8?t=672)

Have a great journey in your React learnings ;-)

**Edit**: the error you are getting:

```
-Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///D:/Ventures/React%20tutorial/script.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, isolated-app, brave, https, chrome-untrusted, data, chrome-extension, chrome.

-GET file:///D:/Ventures/React%20tutorial/script.js
...
```

is caused by opening the file directly in the browser (hint: `...at file:///...`).

Also the part in the error message `only supported for protocol schemes: http, ..., https` indicates that you are not using a proper protocol, since you are using the file protocol (`file://`), and therefore you should change to a supported protocol, like `http://` or `https://`.

You can easily and quickly achieve this by using a VSCode extension like `Live Server` by Ritwick Dey.

Once installed, just right-click the file you want served, eg. `index.html`, choose `Open with Live Server` and the extension takes care of the rest by opening the file in your default browser, serving it with the right protocol. You can see in the address bar of the browser that the url now starts with http: `http://localhost...`.

This should eliminate the error message you get.

As an aside you could also look into a more "proper" way of starting a React project using [create-react-app](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html#create-react-app)

Comment: Thanks @Bqardi for the explanation. I actually tried this but i was getting an error where the .js script was being identified as a SKR, which i thought was a bigger issue. I have edited the original thread to reflect these different attempts.